# класс Text Field в Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Скажите, как называется метод, который считывает данные с TextField'a? И напишите пример его использования в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    TextField text = new TextField();
    String value = text.getText();
```

Создаем объект класса TextField и далее , где нам нужно , получаем текст , который записан в нужном нам TextField.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!